# How to apply crank-nicolson method in python to a wave equation like schrodinger's

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

I'm trying to do a particle in a box simulation with no potential field. Took me some time to find out that simple explicit and implicit methods break unitary time evolution so I resorted to crank-nicolson, which is supposed to be unitary. But when I try it I find that it still is not so. I'm not sure what I'm missing.. The formulation I used is this:

[image: formula 1]

where T is the tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix for the second derivative wrt x and

[image: formula 2]

The system simplifies to

[image: formula 3]

The A and B matrices are:
[image]

I just solve this linear system for [image] using the sparse module. The math makes sense and I found the same numeric scheme in some papers so that led me to believe my code is where the problem is.

Here's my code so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
from scipy import sparse

# Spatial discretisation
N = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
dx = x[1] - x[0]


# Time discretisation
K = 10000
t = np.linspace(0, 10, K)
dt = t[1] - t[0]

alpha = (1j * dt) / (2 * (dx ** 2))

A = sparse.csc_matrix(toeplitz([1 + 2 * alpha, -alpha, *np.zeros(N-4)]), dtype=np.cfloat)  # 2 less for both boundaries
B = sparse.csc_matrix(toeplitz([1 - 2 * alpha, alpha, *np.zeros(N-4)]), dtype=np.cfloat)

# Initial and boundary conditions (localized gaussian)
psi = np.exp((1j * 50 * x) - (200 * (x - .5) ** 2)) 
b = B.dot(psi[1:-1])
psi[0], psi[-1] = 0, 0

for index, step in enumerate(t):
    # Within the domain
    psi[1:-1] = spsolve(A, b)

    # Enforce boundaries
    # psi[0], psi[N - 1] = 0, 0

    b = B.dot(psi[1:-1])
    # Square integration to show if it's unitary
    print(np.trapz(np.abs(psi) ** 2, dx))
```

Comment: You get only unitary steps in this way if `T` is anti-symmetric, if the transpose resp. adjoint of `T` is `-T`. This might happen for a simple transport equation, but quite probably not for a Schödinger equation which contains second derivatives.

Comment: Crank-Nicolson works fine for the heat equation with is a diffusion equation. They both result in Tridiagonal Symmetric Toeplitz matrices. The only difference with this is the unitarity requirement and the complex terms. Can you point me somewhere I can read up on the antisymmetry requirement you mentionned?

Comment: Perhaps I have to amend the previous statement, as the Laplace operator in the Schrödinger equation has a factor `i`, so that the anti-symmetry can be achieved. Then I wonder why your matrices `A,B` are not tri-diagonal, if I understand the construction commands correctly.

Comment: *"If r is not given, r == conjugate(c) is assumed."* This is wrong in this case, the general middle entries should be `[.., -alpha, 1+2*alpha, -alpha, ...]`, but with `alpha` imaginary you get an unwanted sign flip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are relying on the Toeplitz constructor to produce a symmetric matrix, so that the entries below the diagonal are the same as above the diagonal. However, the documentation for `scipy.linalg.toeplitz(c, r=None)` says not *"transpose"*, but

> *"If r is not given, r == conjugate(c) is assumed."

so that the resulting matrix is self-adjoint. In this case this means that the entries above the diagonal have their sign switched.

---

It makes no sense to first construct a dense matrix and then extract a sparse representation. Construct it as sparse tridiagonal matrix from the start, using [`scipy.sparse.diags`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html)

```
A = sparse.diags([ (N-3)*[-alpha], (N-2)*[1+2*alpha], (N-3)*[-alpha]], [-1,0,1], format="csc");
B = sparse.diags([ (N-3)*[ alpha], (N-2)*[1-2*alpha], (N-3)*[ alpha]], [-1,0,1], format="csc");
```

Comment: This solved the issue so thanks a lot. Just for the sake of precision I wanted to add that the syntax to construct the matrices is `sparse.diags` not `diag` like numpy.